# Small continuity error in Red Seas Under Red Skies?

Tags: gentlemen-bastards

In [Scott Lynch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Lynch)'s [*Red Seas Under Red Skies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Seas_Under_Red_Skies), Locke, explicitly in the persona of **Mordavai Fehrwight**, purchases four bespoke chairs from a master furniture builder in Salon Corbeau. However, when Locke is later being interviewed alone by Zamira Drakasha after the pirate captain and her crew rescued him and Jean from being cast adrift on the Sea of Brass, she describes papers—including a work order for some chairs—as being in the name of **Leocanto Kosta**.

Is this a continuity error? Or did Locke forge a work order for the chairs under the name he assumed in Tal Verrar? This seems odd, since the story he gave Requin about the chairs, was that he won them against a gambling debt.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't it that Mordavai Fehrwight was the servant buying them on behalf of Lecanto Kosta? Fehrwight and Kosta seem to be cover identities Jean and Locke use frequently and interchangably.

Comment: I do not think so. Mordavai Fehrwight introduced himself as serving the House of bel Serrethon of Emberlain, while the name Leocanto Kosta hailed from the coast of the Iron Sea.